# Bind variables to constants in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I want to write a program that takes a list and a set of constants and binds variables in the list to the constants.  I only want one constant to be bound to a particular variable. For example:

```
x:-
    C1=[p,r,o,X,r,a,Y,Y,Z,n,X],
    bind_vars(C1,[g,m,i],[],Map).
```

Here I want `C1` to be `[p,r,o,g,r,a,m,m,i,n,g].`

I have the below implementation. Can it be improved in terms of efficiency?

```
bind_vars([], _, Map,Map).
bind_vars([V|Vs],Consts,Map1,Map2):-
  var(V),!,
  member(C,Consts),
  \+memberchk(_-C,Map1),!,
  V=C,
  bind_vars(Vs,Consts,[V-C|Map1],Map2).
bind_vars([_|Vs],Consts,Map1,Map2):-
  bind_vars(Vs,Consts,Map1,Map2).
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
?- C1=[p,r,o,X,r,a,Y,Y,Z,n,X],
   term_variables(C1, [g,m,i]).
C1 = [p, r, o, g, r, a, m, m, i, n, g],
X = g,
Y = m,
Z = i.
```